# Parse XML column in redshift table

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, xml-parsing, amazon-redshift

I have table in redshift which have XML column. I am looking for options to parse this XML and get some values as columns in other table in redshift.

```
sample xml - ('<person><name>John</name><age>25</age></person>')
```

Above XML stored in column in redshift table and I want to parse this column and get the name from XML in redshift query.

Please suggest is there any functions support XML Parse/extract in redshift to parse xml columns and if not is there any way we can achieve this(I tried in redshift documents but didn't see any documentation regarding XML parsing).

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

Redshift doesn't have XML support.

I think there are only two options:

1. Unload this column to s3, use AWS Lambda to convert it from XML to JSON, and copy it to table.
2. Create udf for it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html